# Serverless.yml AWS Lambda Embedding EJS Template body parameters into handler.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm trying to embed an EJS template named 'ui.ejs' into handler.js.
The aim is to capture URL query parameters, then pass them to a function name 'ui.js' to capture data, that data is then passed onto the EJS UI template called 'ui.ejs'.
The script works just fine, but the actual web page looks scrumbled and wierd.
The actual web page UI looks something like this.

```
"\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n \r\n \r\n"
\r\n\r\n Next Page -> \r\n\r\n
\r\n\r\n <- Previous Page \r\n\r\n
```

Is it a problem with the stringify parsing?
Thanks in advance..!

Here's the handler.js code:

```js
import {ui} from './index.js';
var ejs = require('ejs');
var fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// Implementing the UI
export async function UserInterface(event, context, callback) {

    // Capture data event
    const e = event.queryStringParameters;

    // Get UI parameters
    let params = await ui(e);

    var htmlContent = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(process.cwd(), './views/' + 'ui.ejs'), 'utf8');

    var template = ejs.compile(htmlContent);

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: { 'Content-type': 'text/html' },
      body: JSON.stringify(template(params)),
      };

};
```

Answer (score 0):

The Fix:

Replacing 'body:JSON.stringify(template(params))' with 'body:template(params)' got rid of the '\r\n\r\n\n\r'.

But the css files and images are still not working in the web page.

How do I configure the CSS and the images directories to load into the web page?

handler.js

```js
import {ui} from './index.js';
var ejs = require('ejs');
var fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// Implementing the UI
export async function UserInterface(event, context, callback) {

    // Capture data event
    const e = event.queryStringParameters;

    // Get UI parameters
    let params = await ui(e);

    var htmlContent = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(process.cwd(), './views/' + 'ui.ejs'), 'utf8');

    var template = ejs.compile(htmlContent);

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: { 'Content-type': 'text/html' },
      body: template(params),
      };

};
```

The ui.js looks something like this:

ui.js

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"><!-- Link to bootstrap library-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/assets/css/materialize.min.css"><!-- Link to materialize library-->  
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/svg" href="/public/assets/img/site/logo.svg"/><!-- Link to title icon logo-->
    <title><%= title %></title>
</head>
<body>
```

And the index view engine like this:

index.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); // configure express to use public folder
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views'); // set express to look in this folder to render our view
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // configure template engine
```